# why the (typescript) generic cannot be assigned.how to fix it

Tags: typescript, generics

`aa` is not compatible with `A`

```
interface A<T, P> {
    b?: (input:T) => T
    c?: (input:P) => P
}

interface B extends A<number, string> {}

const aa: B = {
    // (property) A<number, string>.c?: ((input: string) => string) | undefined
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((input: string) => string) | undefined'.(2322)
    // input.tsx(31, 5): The expected type comes from property 'c' which is declared here on type 'B'
    c: 'xxx'
}
```

---

Some of the problems constructed above fail to express the problem, but this one does:

```
interface HttpResponse<T = any> {
    ok: boolean;
    data: T;
    status: number;
    statusText: string;
    headers: any;
    usingCache?: boolean;
}
declare class HttpError extends Error {
    __hRestHttpError: boolean;
    name: 'HttpError';
    code: number;
    status: number;
    constructor(message: any);
}

const all: HttpError | HttpResponse<any> = {
    // Type '{ return: HttpError; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpError | HttpResponse<any>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'return' does not exist in type 'HttpError | HttpResponse<any>'.
    return new HttpError('dd')
}
```

`typeA` Assigned to `typeA | typeB`

Comment: You said `B`s would have a `c` prop that is `(input: string) => string`, a *function*. `'xxx'` is just a `string`.

Comment: You've specified that `c` is a *function* that takes `P` and produces `P`. Since `B` assigns `P` to be `string`, the `c` should take a string and produce a string. However, you assign it to just a normal string, not a function.

Comment: Sorry, there's something wrong with the example. Let me reconstruct it.

Comment: I found the crux of the problem while constructing it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your interface you're sating that `c` is a function taking input of type `P` and returning type `P`. In `c` you assign a string value. I'm unsure what your usecase is, but if it's indeed a function you can resolve this by

```
interface A<T, P> {
  b?: (input: T) => T;
  c?: (input: P) => P;
}

interface B extends A<number, string> {}

const aa: B = {
  // (property) A<number, string>.c?: ((input: string) => string) | undefined
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((input: string) => string) | undefined'.(2322)
  // input.tsx(31, 5): The expected type comes from property 'c' which is declared here on type 'B'
  c: (input: string) => 'xxx',
};
```

On the other hand, if you want `c` to be string you resolve it by

```
interface A<T, P> {
  b?: (input: T) => T;
  c?: P;
}

interface B extends A<number, string> {}

const aa: B = {
  // (property) A<number, string>.c?: ((input: string) => string) | undefined
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((input: string) => string) | undefined'.(2322)
  // input.tsx(31, 5): The expected type comes from property 'c' which is declared here on type 'B'
  c: 'xxx',
};
```